# How can I do a loop of url to scrape it?

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping

I want to screap a web site with 10 pages. I created a function to screap the web site, but I needed put all 10 urls, one after one, like this:

```
scraper <- function(link){
  page = read_html(link)
  titulo = page %>% html_nodes("h4 a") %>% html_text()
  tipo = page %>% html_nodes("h4+ .row .col-md-4") %>% html_text()
  data = page %>% html_nodes("p.col-md-6") %>% html_text()
  protocolo = page %>% html_nodes(".row:nth-child(3) .col-md-4") %>% html_text()
  situacao = page %>% html_nodes(".row~ .row+ .row p.col-md-4:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()
  regime = page %>% html_nodes("p.col-md-4:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text()
  quorum = page %>% html_nodes(".col-md-4~ .col-md-4+ .col-md-4") %>% html_text()
  autoria = page %>% html_nodes(".row:nth-child(5) .col-md-12") %>% html_text()
  assunto = page %>% html_nodes(".row:nth-child(6) .col-md-12") %>% html_text()
  
  result <- data.frame(titulo, tipo, data, protocolo, situacao, regime, quorum, autoria, assunto)
  
  return(result)
}

link1 <- "https://santabarbara.siscam.com.br/Documentos/Pesquisa/74?Pesquisa=Simples&Pagina=1&Documento=117&Modulo=8&AnoInicial=2022"
result1 <- scraper(link1)

link2 <- "https://santabarbara.siscam.com.br/Documentos/Pesquisa/74?Pesquisa=Simples&Pagina=2&Documento=117&Modulo=8&AnoInicial=2022"
result2 <- scraper(link2)
```

How can I put all link jut once? Maybe doing a loop?

Comment: Put your links in a list `link_list <- c(link1, link2)`, and then `lapply(link_list, scraper)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The urls for your pages differ only by the `Pagina=` part. Hence you could easily create loop over the pages and create the URLs dynamically for which I use a small custom function and `purrr::map_df` which will bind the results into one dataframe.

For the reprex I only loop over the first two pages:

```r
library(rvest)

make_url <- function(page) {
  paste0(
    "https://santabarbara.siscam.com.br/Documentos/Pesquisa/74?Pesquisa=Simples&Pagina=",
    page, "&Documento=117&Modulo=8&AnoInicial=2022"
  )
}

result <- purrr::map_df(1:2, function(page) {
  url <- make_url(page)
  scraper(url)
}, .id = "page")

dim(result)
#> [1] 30 10

unique(result$page)
#> [1] "1" "2"
```